# How to send one remainder mail per day about the pending task for approve in Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating workflow for approve reject task.first level is Reviewer next level is Head.

I created following workflow.

[image]

```
 Execute SQL          - waiting approve SMS to Reviewer.
 Notification         - Waiting approve Mail to Reviewer.
 Wait for Item update - Check status (not equal) Awaiting Approval from Reviewer
 Set a condition      - Check status (Equal) Awaiting Approval from Head
```

Reviewer receive sms and mail related to waiting approve Task.

Suppose the Reviewer not responding for three contentious day workflow pending on wait for item update.

Work flow need to send one mail per day about the pending task for your approve to Reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Flexi-Task, You can configure it to send reminders (as many as you wish), the gap between reminders, and if need be can choose to delegate the task to someone else.